# Remove or edit object name in admin.TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many

My tabular inline in the admin looks like this :

[image: tabularinline]

How do I get rid of the `DateDeCotisation_adherents object` phrase ?

For bonus points, why are there three empty lines at the bottom ?

## admin.py

```
class DatesDeCotisationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DateDeCotisation.adherents.through
    readonly_fields = ['datedecotisation']
    can_delete = False
```

## models.py

```
class DateDeCotisation(models.Model):

    date = models.DateTimeField()
    adherents = models.ManyToManyField(Adherent, related_name='adherents_du_jour')

    def __str__(self): return self.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "date de cotisation".encode('utf-8')
        verbose_name_plural = "dates de cotisation".encode('utf-8')
        ordering = ['-date']
```

Comment: Regarding the extra three fields at the bottom, just setting "extra = 0" in my TabularInline class cleared them.

Answer (score 2):

That inline should take the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` from the inner `Meta` class of the model [according to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name).  Yet, i just dumped your code into the latest django and it actually doesn't (or, maybe, it only doesn't do it when you use `.through`, nevertheless).

Fortunately, you can always override that by setting `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` directly inside the `InlineModelAdmin`, i.e.

```
class DatesDeCotisationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DateDeCotisation.adherents.through
    readonly_fields = ['datedecotisation']
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name = 'date de cotisation for adherent'
    verbose_name_plural = 'date de cotisation for adherent'

class AdherentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DatesDeCotisationInline]

admin.site.register(models.Adherent, AdherentAdmin)
```

(Sorry for the "for" there but i do not speak French)

The admin appears as follows in Django 1.10:

[image: django tabular inline]

---

On a small note you shall never need to do `.encode('utf-8')` in python 3.  Its stings are UTF-8 by default.

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "date de cotisation".encode('utf-8')
    verbose_name_plural = "dates de cotisation".encode('utf-8')
```

(I assume you're on python 3 since you're using `__str__`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I'll try it out. And is there a way to get rid of the phrase altogether ? "For" woud be "pour" in french !

Comment: seems like it's not working out, still getting the same result even after setting verbose_name and its plural in my admin :s

Comment: I used the latest django release (1.10 as of this writing) to perform my tests.  According to the documentation that field in `InlineModelAdmin` is pretty old so i suspect instead the way you might be registering your tabular inline.  I have updated my answer with the way i performed the `admin.site.register`.

Answer (score 2):

In Django 3, the title of each object for inline admin (`DateDeCotisation_adherents object` in the original post) comes from the model's `__str__` method. Also the extra lines are likely because of the `extra` attribute of the inline admin class. The default set in `admin.InlineModelAdmin` (parent of Stacked and Tabular inline) has `extra = 3`. In your inline admin, set `extra = 0`. Feel free to take a look at all the options in [`django.contrib.admin.options.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py).